# Sql Python: How to sort database before opening?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, scrapy

```
import sys
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi    
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings 
import hashlib
from scrapy import log
import MySQLdb
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

settings = get_project_settings()


class ZillowSamplePipeline(object):    

def __init__(self):    
    dbargs = settings.get('DB_CONNECT')    
    db_server = settings.get('DB_SERVER')    
    dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool(db_server, **dbargs)    
    self.dbpool = dbpool 

def __del__(self):    
    self.dbpool.close()    

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)    
    return item    

def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    #doesnt allow duplicates.
    tx.execute("select * from test where date = %s and title =%s", (item['date'], item['title'] ))
    result = tx.fetchone()
    if result:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:
    #insert data
        tx.execute(\
            "insert into test (title, number, date) "
            "values (%s, %s, %s)",
            (item['title'],
             item['number'],
             item['date']))
        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        #re-organize data  
        tx.execute("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY title")


def handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)
```

Here is the pipelines for my scrapy project to crawl data and upload to a mysql database. I am able to scrape all the data and upload it to the database. My only problem/ question is after i execute this code i am able to get everything on the database but i am unable to see the database sorted out. Which i am doing through this line tx.execute("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY title"). So i want to order the table by the title so i see the same title beneath each other separated by the date. Instead of the different amount of data scraped for the same date. When i execute the query above in MYSQL it shows me the data as i want it shown but when i execute the code and open my SQL i don't see the database already sorted out based on the title. i want the database to be sorted by the title so no matter how many times i run the code it still sorts all information based on title.

Comment: So you want the database table to be pre-sorted in the table already? not sure I follow. Usually your query would sort the data, no matter how the data is stored (usually incremental).

Comment: Hey i cant post pictures but i am able to do upload them to a host site and post urls. The first one is what i am getting from the code. the second picture is the one that shows how i want the data. the third is a csv file that i want to create with the data already sorted out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the Select statement will get the data for you ordered by title which works as expected. It does not actually reorder the internals of the database. So whenever you need to get data ordered by title, you must have ORDER BY title in yoru query. There is no way to guarantee the order your rows come back by applying a function to the database and all future queries will comeback in that order.